# Better way to find the powers of 2

Tags: python, exponential

I am new to python. Is `1 << n` is always better than `2 ** n`? Why or Why not?

Are there any better ways to find the powers of 2?

Comment: That's of course implementation-dependent. As for cpython, see http://bugs.python.org/issue21420

Comment: I think, that `1 << n` is the fastest way to get power of 2, as computers use binary calculation system. So it is needed to do just a shift to the right. And `1 << n` will perform that shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important programming tenet: don't over-optimise prematurely.

Given that `1 << n` will be performed in *integer arithmetic* which significantly limits the results space, the fastest way would be to precompute them and use a lookup table (e.g. a simple array). For a 64 bit unsigned integral types such a table would only have 64 entries.

(In C++ you could even evaluate them at compile time with a bit of template trickery.)

Comment: I can't understand what you have given in the brackets "with a bit of template trickery". If you don't mind could you please brief it?

Comment: I only threw the C++ bit in for a bit of fun: ought not to expand given the question is tagged python. You'd have to ask as a separate question "Can you pre-compute a table of powers of 2 using templates".

Answer (score 4):

`<<` and `**` works almost same when compare to time complexity, result can be seen, 
`pow` works faster when values are small then these but for large values it works slow

```
In [108]: %timeit pow(2, 2)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 127 ns per loop

In [104]: timeit 1<<2
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 ns per loop

In [105]: timeit 2**2
10000000 loops, best of 3: 24.5 ns per loop


In [111]: %timeit  1<<10
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ns per loop

In [112]: %timeit  2**10
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.5 ns per loop

In [113]: %timeit pow(2, 10)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 167 ns per loop

In [114]: %timeit  1<<10000
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.5 ns per loop

In [115]: %timeit  2**10000
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ns per loop

In [116]: %timeit pow(2, 10000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: @Alvaro for large values yes.but in real time programming it not count that much prior, so yipppi to use.