# Can you pre-compute a table of powers of 2 using templates

Tags: c++, exponential

When I asked a question, that states what is the fastest way to find the powers of 2, I get the answer "precompute them and use a lookup table".

How can I pre-compute a table of powers of 2 using templates?

Link to my previous question: [Better way to find the powers of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035753/better-way-to-find-the-powers-of-2/27035980?noredirect=1#comment42592693_27035980)

Comment: Yes you can. It's been done. But you could consider hardcoding them too

Comment: Is indirection through a lookup table really faster than simple bit shifting? Have you measured that?

Comment: Not a direct answer, so I'll post a comment: I think there is no point in generating a table of powers of 2 using templates because lookup tables are commonly used when you don't know the exponent at compile time (otherwise you'd just use a constant...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
constexpr std::array<unsigned long long, 16> LUT = {
     1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768 };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template <int N>
struct pow2 
{
    enum { value = 2 * pow2<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct pow2<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

void foo()
{
    const int x = pow2<4>::value; // == 16
    const int y = pow2<0>::value; // == 1
    int arr[x] = {0}; // Because x is constant
}
```

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/RUfCG4)
Still I would prefer `1U << n` over `pow2<n>::value` unless there are strong evidences of performance degradation.